# xp_cmdshell on SQL Server Linux Public Preview

Tags: sql-server, linux, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I am using the Public Preview of SQL Server 2016 on Linux.
I am trying to run xp_cmdshell and get the following error.
I suspect it has to do with permissions but have no idea how to fix this.
I have spent many hours searching for some answers but there seems to be little support for SQL Server on Linux.
I am running this using an administrator account.
SQL Server is installed on Ubuntu 16.4 (as recommended).
I connect to it with Microsoft SQL Management Studio running on Windows 10.

**SQL code:**

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLtext, no_output
```

**Error message:**

> Msg 15121, Level 16, State 21, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1 [Batch
>   Start Line 159] An error occurred during the execution of xp_cmdshell.
>   A call to 'CreateProcess' failed with error code: '2'.

Comment: I believe that xp_cmdshell isn't moving over to the Linux version of SQL Server, I'll check for sources though. Edit: it was Episode 70 of the SQL Data Partners podcast which is an interview with Travis Wright (program manager for SQL Server on Linux migration) http://sqldatapartners.com/podcast/

Comment: OK, thank you for a quick answer. If xp_cmdshell is not going to be available on Linux then how can I pass commands to shell using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @smucha that is a separate question and should generate its own question on SO

Comment: For reference, it's at minute 34 of that podcast

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes#GA) for SQL Server 2017 General Availability, the following are currently not available on Linux:

**Database engine**

- Transactional replication
- Merge replication
- Stretch DB
- Polybase
- Distributed query with 3rd-party connections
- System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.)
- Filetable
- CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set
  Buffer Pool Extension

**SQL Server Agent**

- Subsystems: CmdExec, PowerShell, Queue Reader, SSIS, SSAS, SSRS
- Alerts
- Log Reader Agent
- Change Data Capture
- Managed Backup

**High Availability**

- Database mirroring

**Security**

- Extensible Key Management
- AD Authentication for Linked Servers
- AD Authenticatin for Availibility Groups (AGs)

**Services**

- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server R services
- StreamInsight
- Analysis Services
- Reporting Services
- Data Quality Services
- Master Data Services

Microsoft also has a list of Release notes and a list of unsupported features [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes).

Comment: Note to everyone - this answer is outdated. Fulltext dearch, SQL agent etc are all available now with GA (general availability) release of SQL 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes#GA

Comment: @jitbit I went ahead and updated my answer to reflect the most recent version

Comment: Any update for SQL 2019?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes-2019?view=sql-server-ver15&preserve-view=true